# Meteor User Property

Tags: meteor

I'd like to be able to mark users as "admin" in the Meteor auth system, and allow that user to do special things, as well as show some gui elements I wouldn't show if they weren't an admin. I've already tried setting an "admin" property on the user object, which would work fine on the server side (for the RPCs for the admin actions), however I need to access it on the client side to change the rendering of the page, and it appears only emails is sent with the Meteor.user() object.

Basic question: How can I assign a user-specific property that both the server and client can see?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To anyone in the future, simply assign the value in the users table in the database. You can publish additional fields to the user using the following:

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
     return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {fields: {'admin': 1}});
});
```

And on the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe("userData");
```

Poof. Straight from [the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_user).

Comment: LOL! It's funny that you asked a question and then answered it yourself 2 minutes later

Comment: Nice, this works well, just as a comment after you've subscribed you can access the data with `Meteor.user().admin`

Answer (score 0):

You can also add properties in "profile" attribute of the user. profile attribute is alrealy populated to client side :

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: userId}, {$set: {'profile.admin': 1}});

//on client side
Meteor.user().profile.admin
```

Comment: You do *not* want to do this. If you do this, any user by default can make themselves an admin. Due to default read/write rules on the profile object. You'd want to create this field outside of the profile object. Something like: `Meteor.users.update( {_id: id}, { $set: { isAdmin: true } } );` http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_user "http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_user"