# Display a profile photo with Meteor

Tags: image, meteor, cloudinary

I want to display a profile photo for users. I have a default photo that is saved when a user first gets an account.

```
Accounts.createUser({
      email: email,
      username: username,
      password: password,
      profile: {
        profilePhotoUrl: "..."
      }
}
```

I want to display this photo on the navbar:

```
<img src="{{c.url profile.profilePhotoUrl format=format}}">
```

The photo seems to display sometimes and not others. I believe this is a problem with subscription.

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function:
meteor.js:888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at cloudinary_url (lepozepo_cloudinary.js:338)
    at Object.$.cloudinary.url (lepozepo_cloudinary.js:432)
    at Object.Cloudinary._helpers.url (lepozepo_cloudinary.js:799)
    at spacebars.js:245
    at Spacebars.call (spacebars.js:172)
    at Spacebars.mustacheImpl (spacebars.js:109)
    at Object.Spacebars.mustache (spacebars.js:113)
    at HTML.DIV.HTML.BUTTON.HTML.IMG.src (template.header.js:57)
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (blaze.js:2197)
    at Blaze._HTMLJSExpander.def.visitAttribute (blaze.js:2125)
```

I'm not sure what this means, but I think it is receiving null since I haven't subscribed to the profile.profilePhotoUrl. How can I make this available for the entire site? I also would like to show other people's profile photos so how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `profile.profilePhotoUrl` will be undefined until the current user data is loaded from the server. The problem here is that you `c.url` helper goes crazy unless it receives a valid `string`, which is unfortunate.

There are several ways out of here, one of them would be to create another helper

```
var defaultId = "..."; // make sure this is a valid public id

Template.registerHelper('getProfilePhoto', function () {
  return (this.profile && this.profile.profilePhoto) || defaultId;
});
```

which makes sure your "profilePhoto" is not only a string but also a valid id. Now, replacing your template code with

```
<img src="{{c.url getProfilePhoto format=format}}">
```

should fix the issue you're describing.

If there's not natural choice for `defaultId`, you can just use a custom url if the `profilePhoto` is not provided, so

```
{{#if profile.profilePhoto}}
  <img src="{{c.url profile.profilePhotoUrl format=format}}">
{{else}}
  <img src="/a/path/for/default/avatar.png">
{{/if}}
```

You can also use some loading indicator instead of default image.

**Edit**

If you're using some kind of routing, e.g. `iron:router`, in your application then it's also possible to wait and not render your templates until the user data arrives, so

```
Router.route('/user/profile/page', {
  // ...
  waitOn: function () {
    return {
      ready: function () {
        return !!Meteor.user();
      }
    };
  },
});
```

However, I wouldn't recommend that because it affects the site "loading" time and so the user experience as well.

Comment: I'm still having problems loading it. When I am on my profile page, the picture loads fine. When I navigate to another tab, my console displays 400 bad request. This is what is being requested: http://res.cloudinary.com/dole39ib3/image/upload/ . And when I check the console it says that X-Cld-Error:public_id (upload/) is invalid . So for some reason, when I'm not on the profile page it doesn't include anything after the upload/ like it should.

Comment: Can you provide some more details on how the `c.url` is working?

Comment: I've been trying to find anything I can, but can't locate it https://github.com/Lepozepo/cloudinary I just was following the example that is given on the main page. The only difference is that I used the photo url rather than public id

Answer (score 0):

not all properties of the user are published by default. You have to add them explicitly by adding them to a `UserData` publication.

You can find an example in this answer: [Meteor User Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103770/meteor-user-property)

Also, depending on how you defined your routing, you need to resubscribe to the `userData` publication in order to have the data available, or you can put the subscription in the template where the picture is shown.